# How do Brawler's Flurry and Power Attack interact?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature

For reference, [the rules about the brawler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/#TOC-Brawler-s-Flurry-Ex-) indicate:

> A brawler applies her full Strength modifier to her damage rolls for all attacks made with brawler’s flurry, whether the attacks are made with an off-hand weapon or a weapon wielded in both hands.

While browsing at random I read in [this gdoc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1w-fFC7g7rUf-IGY-HJrV5E7j9xPcD2A67RekruJp1_o/edit) the following lines:

> Brawler’s Flurry does not grant 1.5x Strength-to-damage while using a weapon two-handed, so you miss out on some potential damage there.
>
> Brawler’s Flurry does allow you to get extra damage from Power Attack when using a weapon wielded in two hands though.

The first line seems ok, but I find the second one strange. Does Power Attack really interact that way with Brawler's Flurry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Power attack states:

> You can choose to take a –1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on all melee damage rolls. This bonus to damage is increased by half (+50%) if you are making an attack with a two-handed weapon, a one handed weapon using two hands, or a primary natural weapon that adds 1-1/2 times your Strength modifier on damage rolls. This bonus to damage is halved (–50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon.

A brawler's class features in no way alter the handedness of wielded weapons, so there's no reason to think that Power Attack would function differently than normal.

Answer (score 2):

[Brawler's Flurry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/#TOC-Brawler-s-Flurry-Ex-) does not affect [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/) in any form, only the extra damage from Strenght (0.5x for off-hand, 1.5x for two-handed). As such, a brawler using any of their restricted weapons with both hands still would gain **+3 per increment of Power Attack** instead of +2, while only gaining the normal Strenght Bonus.

That is because you *can* use two-handed weapons with [Brawler's Flurry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/brawler/#TOC-Brawler-s-Flurry-Ex-):

> Starting at 2nd level, a brawler can make a brawler’s flurry as a full-attack action. When doing so, a brawler has the Two-Weapon Fighting feat when attacking with any combination of unarmed strikes, weapons from the close fighter weapon group, or **weapons with the “monk” special feature**.

Weapons like the [quarterstaff](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/quarterstaff), [monk's spade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/monk-s-spade), [sansetsukon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/sansetsukon-three-section-staff) or [tigerfork](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/tiger-fork) are all two-handed weapons, or can be wielded two-handed, for quarterstaves (a [double weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons#wpn-quality-double)).

Not only that, but several weapons from the fighter's close weapon group are one-handed weapons, instead of light weapons, and as such, could also be wielded with both hands for increased damage. Like the [scizore](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/scizore), [heavy shields](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/shield-heavy-wooden-or-steel), [dan bong](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/dan-bong), [nine ring broadsword](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/broadsword-nine-ring) or [the double chicken saber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/double-chicken-saber).